# Issue with Scheduler task in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler, splunk, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Scheduler to run automatically with fixeddelay = 120000. 
There are two issues

1). In the scheduler there is call to another service, For each iteration service has to be called once but in this case calling twice. Two Instances calling [APP/PROC/WEB/0] and [APP/PROC/WEB/1]

```
12/17/18
3:15:18.751 PM  
422 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:45:18.751861+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/0] - - 2018-12-17 09:45:18 INFO  Path.ClassName.callWorkflow(WorkFlowService.java:53)-|||||Response from Bonita :: {"taskId":0,"statusCode":0,"processVersion":"1.8","caseId":790,"processName":"ValidationFlow","statusMessage":"Success"}
host =  1.2.3.4 source =    tcp:1234 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog
12/17/18
3:15:18.258 PM  
422 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:45:18.258514+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/1] - - 2018-12-17 09:45:18 INFO  Path.ClassName.callWorkflow(WorkFlowService.java:53)-|||||Response from Bonita :: {"taskId":0,"statusCode":0,"processVersion":"1.8","caseId":789,"processName":"ValidationFlow","statusMessage":"Success"}

host =  2.3.4.5 source =    tcp:1234 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog
```

2). Before finishing the first iteration second iteration is starting which is behaving like fixedrate, though i am using fixedDelay.

Splunk Logs :

```
12/17/18
2:55:14.657 PM  
280 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:25:14.657142+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/1] - - 2018-12-17 09:25:14 INFO  Path.ClassName.execute(OrderScheduler.java:28)-|||||END OrderScheduler :: execute
host =  1.2.3.4 source =    tcp:9408 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog
12/17/18
2:55:14.441 PM  
282 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:25:14.441492+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/1] - - 2018-12-17 09:25:14 INFO  Path.ClassName.execute(OrderScheduler.java:26)-|||||START OrderScheduler :: execute
host =  1.2.3.4 source =    tcp:9408 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog
12/17/18
2:53:15.454 PM  
280 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:23:15.454936+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/0] - - 2018-12-17 09:23:15 INFO  Path.ClassName.execute(OrderScheduler.java:28)-|||||END OrderScheduler :: execute
host =  1.2.3.4 source =    tcp:9408 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog
12/17/18
2:53:14.440 PM  
280 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:23:14.440499+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/1] - - 2018-12-17 09:23:14 INFO  Path.ClassName.execute(OrderScheduler.java:28)-|||||END OrderScheduler :: execute
host =  1.2.3.4 source =    tcp:9408 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog
*12/17/18
2:53:13.504 PM  
282 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:23:13.504977+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/0] - - 2018-12-17 09:23:13 INFO  Path.ClassName.execute(OrderScheduler.java:26)-|||||START OrderScheduler :: execute
host =  1.2.3.4 source =    tcp:9408 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog
12/17/18
2:53:13.045 PM  
282 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:23:13.045063+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/1] - - 2018-12-17 09:23:13 INFO  Path.ClassName.execute(OrderScheduler.java:26)-|||||START OrderScheduler :: execute
host =  1.2.3.4 source =    tcp:9408 sourcetype =   rfc5424_syslog*
12/17/18
2:51:13.504 PM  
280 <14>1 2018-12-17T09:21:13.504222+00:00 servicename-serverName 6a5a4df1-f683-4748-986d-aa3e2c289e6d [APP/PROC/WEB/0] - - 2018-12-17 09:21:13 INFO  Path.ClassName.execute(OrderScheduler.java:28)-|||||END OrderScheduler :: execute
```

Code i am using is below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
  }
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class testScheduler() {
@Autowired
private ClassName service;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 120000)
public void start() {
   service.methodName();
 }
}
```

Issue happening only in server side, but in local system it's working fine.
Can any one help me in this issue please.... Thank you

Comment: make sure you are not running two instance .

Comment: or use a distributed lock.

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock